# disable clientside validation in asp,net 4.0

Tags: asp.net

I want to disable clientside validation but only under certain circumstances on a button click, `causesvalidation` is no use as the logic that decides whether the validation is enabled or not lies on the client.

I need some javascript to disable everything and allow the button to submit.

I have a div that is shown or hidden dependent on a radio button value. If the div is hidden, i.e. the radio button is selected then I want the submit button to avoid the validation.  I have tried this:

```
if (radio.val() === 'yes') {
  $('.NavigatorNext').get(0).disableValidation = true;
}
```

But validation still happens.

Comment: Give us an example of one condition to disable the validation? Where does the logic resides "client side" or "server side"?

Comment: @Dalorzo i have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve what you need the simplest could be something like:

```
<input type="button" value="demo" onClick="javascript:Page_ValidationActive = false;" />
```

Better is if you check on the full documentation for [ASP.NET Validations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside)